# AS3 Event Race Condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having some trouble solving a race condition that exists when I instantiate new MovieClip classes with some custom events that fire back before I can store the instances in an associative object.

**Main Class**

```
var pages:Object = {
    "page1":"page1",
    "page2":"page2"
};

for(var pageName:String in pages)
{
    pages[pageName] = buildPage(pageName, onReady);
}

function buildPage(pageName:String, onReady:Function)
{
    var newPage:MovieClip = new (getDefinitionByName(pageClass) as Class)();
    newPage.addEventListener("PAGE_READY", onReady);
    newPage.dispatchEvent(new Event("PAGE_CREATE"));
    return newPage;
}

function onReady(e:Event)
{
    for(var pageName:String in pages)
    {
        trace(typeof pages[pageName]);
    }
}
```

**Page 1 & 2 Classes** extends MovieClip

```
function pageX()
{
    this.addEventListener("PAGE_CREATE",this.onCreate);
}

function onCreate(e:Event)
{
    this.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200x200);
    this.graphics.endFill();

    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("PAGE_READY"));
}
```

Unfortunatley when this all fires off I get:

```
string
string
object
string
```

The original string object still exists before I can store the MovieClip instance for later reference. Any suggestions on how to beat this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does not depict a standard class.
Is this code on the movieclip frames or in separate files?
But as far as posted code I can see your issue is with the PAGE_CREATE event firing before the object has been added to the array.
your are doing

```
newPage.dispatchEvent(new Event("PAGE_CREATE"));
```

before you return the object.
You did not post the full classes so I really can't help you rewrite your code but, from what you posted I would remove the buildPage method completely and put the code in loop then dispatch the event after the object has been added to the array.
Also, another reason, best practice would be not to call a function from a loopif that function does not have a lot of code in it.

```
for(var pageName:String in pages)
{
    var newPage:MovieClip = new (getDefinitionByName(pageClass) as Class)();
    newPage.addEventListener("PAGE_READY", onReady);
    pages[pageName] = newPage;
    newPage.dispatchEvent(new Event("PAGE_CREATE"));
}
```

Comment: I only posted the chunks of the classes that were relevant to the situation instead of the whole class, and I've moved to a setup similar to the one you are describing. I just find it to be dirty code and would love to see if there is a better solution out there. Thanks for reaffirming my problem though, I was beginning to think I was crazy.

Comment: Well like I was saying without you posting the full code I can't help you redesign the classes to a more standard level.